# PHP SQL IF NOT EXISTS won't work

Tags: mysql

I've got a question about SQL (php), I want to INSERT data in my table. But I want to use the IF NOT EXIST value.
What I've tried:

```
INSERT INTO vrienden (id, userid, vriendmetid, accepted) VALUES (null, '1', '20', '0') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM vrienden WHERE userid='1' AND vriendmetid='20')
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, because I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM vrienden WHERE userid='1' AND vriendmetid='20')' at line 1

Thanks.

Comment: `INSERT` doesn't have `WHERE`

Comment: Just add a unique key to your table, try to insert, and wait to see if the insert fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `insert . . . select`, not `insert . . . values`:

```
INSERT INTO vrienden (id, userid, vriendmetid, accepted) 
     SELECT x.*
     FROM (select null as id, '1' as userid, '20' as vriendmetid, '0' as accepted) x
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vrienden v WHERE v.userid = x.userid AND v.vriendmetid = x.vriendmetid);
```

However, you probably shouldn't be doing this in the `INSERT`.  Instead, create a unique index/constraint:

```
create unique index unq_vrienden_userid_vriendmetid on vrienden(userid, vriendmetid);
```

This way, the database will ensure uniqueness of the columns, so your application does not have to.